# Anyone familiar with PHP source code?

Tags: php, c, php-internals

```
zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "ss", &r1, &n, &r2, &m)
```

What's `"ss"` for here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"ss" is  type_spec string

check this rosource out http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/weblinux2/php/ch14_07.htm

Answer (score 3):

The type specifier in your case is `"ss"`. The specifier `s` is for a string. Since you are requesting **two** string parameters you need to supply two `s` as `ss`:

```
zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "ss", &field1 &field1_length, 
                                                       &field2, &field2_length)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is `type_spec`. Check [here](http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/zend-api.zend-parse-parameters.php)

Answer (score 0):

that php function  expects 2 strings parameteres, that's why 2 s's.
every string in php is defined by a pointer and a length. that's why you have

&r1, &n,  -> 1st string
&r2, &m   -> 2nd string.